# _.matchesProperty shorthand in Lodash not working but providing function does

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I'm pretty new to Lodash and I'm having some problems with the shorthand notation on the `_.find` function.

I have the following angular 2 object:

```
export class ProductData {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    type: ProductTypeData;
}
```

I then have an array of ProductData that I created by filtering on product type. I use this array to display values in a dropdown list on to the user. When the user selects a product from the dropdown list I am storing the id in a local variable, productId. When the user closes the dialog I am doing processing on the selected product.

The following code works for me:

```
var self = this;
let selectedProduct = _.find(this.filteredProducts, function(product) { return product.id == self.productId; });
```

I would rather use the `_.matchesProperty` shorthand for Lodash (since it's cleaner to read than assigning the context to a variable) like so:

```
let selectedProduct = _.find(this.filteredProducts, ['id', this.productId]);
```

but that is returning `undefined` for me.

I'm guessing I'm screwing up something fairly simple but I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what.

Comment: A quick loose test seems to indicate it should work. Could it be a lodash version difference? Lodash 2.4.2 's find for example doesn't support the matchesProperty: https://lodash.com/docs/2.4.2#find  Can you try the '_.matches' shorthand instead: `let selectedProduct = _.find(this.filteredProducts, {'id':this.productId});`

Comment: The `_.matches` shorthand gives me the same result